# Como enviar un res.json( ) que esta dentro de un bucle for, usando node (express) y ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, nodejs, express

estoy trabajando con `NodeJS` utilizando `express` con este tengo las rutas como son **POST** y **GET** me conecto a una `bd` y realizo consultas en la **app**, pero tengo una duda sobre el siguiente código:

```
    function getAllDatabases() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            connection.query("SHOW DATABASES;", function (err, result) {
                // console.log(result);
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }

                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    } 

    var data = [];
    function getDataConfig(data_array, res) {

        console.log(data_array);

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            for (let i = 0; i < data_array.length; i++) {
                connection.query("SELECT * FROM " + data_array[i].Database + ".config ", function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }

                    resolve(res.json(result));
                });
            }
        });
    }

router.post('/add_config', function (req, res) {
    var databases = [];
    var data = {
        Dg: req.body.Dg,
        Source: req.body.Source.toLowerCase(),
        Label_1: req.body.Label_1,
        Label_2: req.body.Label_2,
        Label_3: req.body.Label_3,
        Styles: req.body.Styles,
        Method: req.body.Method,
        Intervals: req.body.Intervals,
        allow: req.body.Allow,
        smart: req.body.Smart,
        units: req.body.Units,
        resolution: req.body.Resolution
    }
    getAllDatabases().then(resp => getDataConfig(resp, res));

});
```

quiero saber como poder enviar el **res.json(result);** que esta dentro del segundo **resolve()** en la función `getDataConfig`, al yo hacer el envió de ese `json`, me da el siguiente error

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

la razón la conozco pues  al estar el `res.json` dentro de un bucle envía la respuesta y finaliza de inmediato ese `res.json` funciona como si fuera un **return**, el da el valor y finaliza, hay alguna manera de solucionar este problema?
gracias

Answer (score 1):

Estás iterando sobre un array y en cada loop llamando a  `res.json` que envía la respuesta. No puedes llamar varias veces a `res.json` porque la primera ya envía los headers y da el request por terminado.

Si estás usando la libería nativa de promesas, lo que puedes hacer es devolver un objeto con la salida de todas las respuestas.

```
function getDataConfig(data_array, res) {

    console.log(data_array);
    var promise_array=[],
        results_object={};

    for (let i = 0; i < data_array.length; i++) {
        let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM " + data_array[i].Database + ".config ", function (err, result) {
                results_object[data_array[i].Database]=err? err.message : result;
                resolve();
            });

       });
       promise_array.push(promise);
    }
    return Promise.all(promise_array).then(()=>{
         return res.json(results_object);
    });
}
```

Si te fijas, estoy resolviendo todas las promesas. Pero en `results_object` el valor de la llave `data_array[i].Database` puede ser el conjunto de resultados o el mensaje de error.

Rechazar la promesa cuando hay error causaría que `Promise.all` nunca se resolviera de fallar una de las queries.

Si estuvieras usando una librería mejorada de promesas como [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) podrías usar métodos de conveniencia como `Promise.reduce` o `Promise.each` y además podrías **promisificar** `connection.query` para tratarla en sí como una promesa:

```
const Promise=require('bluebird);
```

Y luego:

```
function getDataConfig(data_array, res) {

    console.log(data_array);
    var promise_array=[],
        results_object={},
        queryAsync = Promise.promisify(connection.query);

    for (let i = 0; i < data_array.length; i++) {
        let promise = queryAsync("SELECT * FROM " + data_array[i].Database + ".config ")
          .then((result)=> {
             results_object[data_array[i].Database]=result;
             return;
          }).catch((err)=>{
             results_object[data_array[i].Database]=err.message;
             return;
          }); 

       });
       promise_array.push(promise);
    }
    return Promise.all(promise_array).then(()=>{
         return res.json(results_object);
    });
}
```